# <p> tag inside <li> tag with counter based on counter-reset forces unwanted new line

Tags: html, css, html-lists, pseudo-element

The CSS `counter-reset` property allows one to automatically number HTML elements (example [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/c/counter-reset/)). In addition to the use demonstrated in the link, this property is also useful for making a continuous ordered list on a webpage when the `<li>` elements do not all occur inside of the same `<ol>` tag.

However, when there is a `<p>` tag inside of the `<li>` tag, this forces the text to appear on a line after the actual counter. Is there any way to prevent this behavior *while still using the `<p>` tag*? That is to say, how can I make the text "Life is bad" in the following minimal working example appear on the same line as its counter *while keeping the text inside of the `<p>` tag in the HTML markup*?

Here's the minimal working example (and on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ru8Fv/)):

The HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <ol>
        <li class="continuous-list">Life is good</li>
        <li class="continuous-list">
            <p>Life is bad</p>
        </li>
    </ol>
    <ol>
        <li class="continuous-list">Life is good</li>
        <li class="continuous-list">Life is good</li>
    </ol>
</div>
```

The CSS:

```
#test {
    counter-reset: continuous-counter;
}
li.continuous-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    counter-increment: continuous-counter;
}
li.continuous-list:before {
    content:"(" counter(continuous-counter)") ";
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because `p` is a *block level element*, you need to make it *inline*

```
ol li p {
    display: inline;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/2dSNU/)

Now the above selector will make ALL the `p` elements inside `ol li` as `display: inline` so as you are using an `id` you can make your selector unique by using

```
div#test ol li p {
    display: inline; /* Or you can use inline-block as well if you are 
                        looking to work with margins and paddings, inline-block 
                        will be handy */
}
```

Comment: Inlining the paragraphs works for just one paragraph, but is there something that can be done if you have two (or more) paragraphs inside the `<li>` element? Changing the `display` to `inline` puts these paragraphs on the same line.

Comment: @AdamLiter use a `br` tag to split them up

Answer (score 0):

Add `float:left` to the `before`

i.e.

```css
li.continuous-list:before {
    float: left;
    content:"(" counter(continuous-counter)") ";
}
```